# How to set Python IDLE in Windows 10 for opening .py files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-idle

Right now my `.py` file opening through visual studio and the Python icon not showing in any `.py` file but previously my all `.py` file was opening in python IDLE.

How to get it back? In `cmd`, if I type `python` then I am getting the python shell which means python is properly installed in my system — but why `.py` file not opening though in python IDLE?

Comment: how to change default programs: https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-customize-your-default-apps-in-windows-and-macos

Comment: Detailed instructions: [Associate Python Files with IDLE](https://www.webucator.com/article/associate-python-files-with-idle/).

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on `.py` file
2. Open with
3. Choose another app
4. More apps
5. Look for another app on this PC
6. Select `C:\Python36\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat`

Note that `C:\Python36` is your Python path.

---

You can find your python path like this :

1. Open Python shell
2. Run this code :

```py
import sys

for p in sys.path:
    print(p)
```

You see a listing of the path information. Your listing may be different, depending on your platform, the version of Python you have installed, and the Python features you have installed.

[image]